# Cookie Cutter Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light

A situation similar to this arose in my high-school modern physics course, and I had a question to ask that I hope someone is willing to answer.

Suppose a circular pad of cookie dough is being rolled down a conveyer belt at a relativistic velocity, *A*.  A circular cookie cutter goes straight down (in the Earth's reference frame) and punches a hole in the pad of cookie dough.

Had this situation occurred at a non-relativistic velocity, it would look something like this:

[image]

Where the length of the cookie dough-cutter is *L*, and *d* is the length of the pad of cookie dough (forgot to label this).

Now, in a situation where the cookie dough moves at a relativistic velocity, the diagram (from the Earth's reference frame) will look more like this:
[image]

In either case, whether the cookie dough is moving at relativistic or non-relativistic speeds, the cookie cutter will slam down on the cookie dough and every event in that instance (the left side of the cut-out cutting the dough, the right side cutting it out, etc.) occur at essentially the same time, ***in the Earth's reference frame***.  That is to say that in the lab reference frame, the events of the cookie cutter edges cutting the dough are all simultaneous.

Because we know that in our lab reference frame that all edges of the cookie cutter will cut the cookie dough basically simultaneously, we know that in any other reference frame that these events will not be simultaneous.

Here is where my question arises.  If you are the cookie dough, moving at relativistic speeds (for instance, 0.8c) how does the cookie cutter appear to you?  Obviously, the cutter will be warped in the same way the cookie dough would be contracted to us.  However, whereas we see the cutter slam down all its edges simultaneously, the cookie dough could not possibly see that.  Otherwise, we would be different directions of contraction/extension once the cookie dough slows down to a speed of zero.  What I mean by this is that, once the cookie dough slows down, we would see it extend in the direction of motion, whereas the cookie dough would see itself extend perpendicular to the direction of motion.

So, if the extension in relation to the direction of motion remains constant, then the time at which the events take place must be different.  Therefore, the cookie dough sees a very warped movement of the cookie cutter that we do not see.

How does the cookie cutter's shape and motion appear to the cookie dough?

Comment: This is a version of the [ladder paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox). Does the Minkowski diagram of figure 6 help?

Answer (score 1):

The cutter has to move at relativistic speeds too.

From the perspective of the dough:

The descending cutting edge appears slanted, with the front of the 'circle' cut before the back.

During its acceleration the cutter's shape warps from the front to slant the other way

After the acceleration the front retracts before the back.

The process takes a finite time, so that the apparently squat elliptical cutter cuts an elongated elliptical hole.